# Htaccess regex working strange

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I am trying to write .htacess file that would catch urls like:

http://www.site.com/pageone.html

http://www.site.com/pagetwo.html

and redirect them to index.php so it would receive '**pageone**' and '**pagetwo**' as GET parameters.

Below is my htacess:

> Options +FollowSymlinks
>
> AuthUserFile /dev/null
>
> AuthGroupFile /dev/null
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteOptions inherit
>
> RewriteRule ^((?:.[^/])+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
>
> AddHandler php5-script .php

The problem with this regexp is that it catches some pages while showing 404 error on others.
And i don't understand this behavior.

For example

http://www.site.com/draw.html

works fine. I get 'draw' as GET parameter in my script.

But

http://www.site.com/draws.html

redirects to 404 page

Could anyone explain what is wrong with my htacess ?

p.s. - i am seeing this on a local Apache server under typical MAMP config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^((?:.[^/])+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

- `^` = anchor at the start of the URI
- `(?:` = extended expression to group without creating a backreference; unsure what the purpose is here.
- `.` = match a single character.
- `[^/]` = match anything that's not a slash
- `+` = all of the above, repeated one or more times
- `.html` = must end in .html
- `$` = anchor the end of the URI.

This code would match, among other things, /ab/cd/ef/foo.html, which will never occur in a per-directory context.
It would ***not*** match odd-length resources or directories, since you explicitly ignore those with `(.[^/])`.

Since you don't specify if multiple subdirectories should be handled or not, just matching what you described can be done much, much easier with:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

For further help with troubleshooting, see the [**RewriteLog documentation**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

Comment: Thanks, it works. And your regexp looks much more elegant. But the question remains - why my regexp is not working ? In fact it won't match any '/ab/cd/ef/foo.html' urls as you have written.

Comment: I would not count blindly on extended PCRE working in mod_rewrite; I have not seen that used in years of apache support.

Comment: He covered that too.  Because your grouping matches two characters, it can only match even-length URLs.  Furthermore, every second character cannot be a slash so `/a/b/c.html` will match and `/ab/c/d.html` won't.  Lastly, the leading slash is removed in `.htaccess` files which reverses the meaning of the previous sentence.

Comment: Not reverse, but if the **first** character is a slash it will never match, regardless of the rest of the URI.